# Создание и получение объектов моделей

Tags: django, django-admin

В админке я могу создавать объект класса User, при этом выбрав project и заполнив поле user. Теперь у меня есть форма base.html, где есть поле user, а поле проекта нет, так  как нахожусь на странице определенного проекта с уникальным id (например: форма находится на странице /project/1/ (id=1)). Вопрос как создавать объект класса User с формы, чтобы он автоматически появился в админке. У меня получилось это сделать, если не учитывать project (ForeignKey). Подскажите, что добавить?

base.html

```
<form action="" method="post">
      <textarea name="name"></textarea>
      <button type="submit">Отправить</button>
</form>
```

models.py

```
class User(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project)
    user = HTMLField(blank=True, null=True)
```

views.py

```
def index(request):
    user = Project.objects.all()
    return render(request, "base.html", {"user": user})

def retro(request):
    a = User.objects.all()
    return render(request, "create.html", {"a": a})

def create(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        tom = User()
        tom.name = request.POST.get("name")
        tom.save()
    return redirect('/')
    else:
        form = UserForm()
    return render(request, 'save.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: передать айди проекта в урл, например.

Comment: берите id проекта из url kwargs

Comment: @ZaArs В админке есть поле project, т.е. выпадающий список, в котором мы можем выбрать. Каждый project имеет свой id. Когда я нахожусь на странице определенного project, заполняю форму и отправляю, надо чтобы в админке по id страницы в поле project выбралось.

Comment: @pythoner В админке есть поле project, т.е. выпадающий список, в котором мы можем выбрать. Каждый project имеет свой id. Когда я нахожусь на странице определенного project, заполняю форму и отправляю, надо чтобы в админке по id страницы в поле project выбралось.

Comment: Тут нужен `long polling`, написать скрипт, представление для админки.

Comment: @pythoner по-другому никак? я даже не знаю что это и как писать

Answer (score 0):

Для начала проверьте, что url у вас следущего вида

Создаете форму ModelForm для пользователя

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['project', 'name']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
       self.fields['project'].widget = HiddenInput() # Скрываем поле
```

Добавляете вьюху в админке, по аналогии с add/change_view, но урезаете функционал до минимума.

Добавляете urls на view в get_urls() метод

Добавляете в шаблон админки модели кнокпку с url на страницу с формой регистрации юзера для этого проекта.

Все

---

Естественно это сложнее, чем было в первом варианте ответа

Comment: Мне не нужно выводить его в шаблоне.

Comment: Там речь об админке идёт

Comment: @pythoner  > Вопрос как создавать объект класса User с формы, чтобы он автоматически появился в админке.  После созранения формы, объект появится в адмике